# ROS dependency Boost 1.58, additional dependency Boost 1.64?

Tags: ros, catkin, boost, 3rd-party-package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I've got a problem here that I seem unable to solve... or even fully get my head around.

ROS itself installs `libboost 1.58` as one of its dependencies. In addition I have a 3rd party dependency for a node of `libboost 1.64`. `Boost 1.58` is installed via `apt` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` as usual and comes with `ros-kinetic-desktop-full`. So deinstalling it isn't an option.

`Boost 1.64` on the other hand is manually built by `cmake/make/make install` and installed in `/usr/local/lib`. This doesn't appear to be an issue in this particular case, actually, but `catkin` warns about not being able to generate a safe linker path. The node actually works. The warning is annoying though, and I'd like to somehow cleanly solve this issue instead of just suppressing the warning. But if there's no other way, I'd go with simply deactivating that particular warning.

How should I deal with this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274016/ros-dependency-boost-1.58,-additional-dependency-boost-1.64?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2017-10-25

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> How should I deal with this?

Ideally: avoid trying to use two different Boost versions on the same machine. Or at least: make sure that they are only visible (ie: findable) by the applications that need them.

Mixing Boost versions like this can lead to subtle and hard to diagnose `SEGFAULT`s and other problems. Even in the case where one Boost library is header only, and linking is not even involved (just search around, the internet is full of examples).

> `Boost 1.64` on the other hand is manually built by `cmake/make/make install` and installed in `/usr/local/lib`. This doesn't appear to be an issue in this particular case, actually, but `catkin` warns about not being able to generate a safe linker path. The node actually works. The warning is annoying though, and I'd like to somehow cleanly solve this issue instead of just suppressing the warning. But if there's no other way, I'd go with simply deactivating that particular warning.

One suggestion: if you're compling the node that needs the newer Boost version yourself (and I assume that is the case, as ROS Kinetic binaries are built against `1.58`), a somewhat clean work-around could be to move the `1.64` artefacts to a location that is not on the default include, linker and search paths. Use the regular CMake knobs to tell the `CMakeLists.txt` that need it (ie: the node that needs `1.64`) where to find it and to require it (something like `find_package(Boost REQUIRED 1.64 EXACT ..)`). It could be that running binaries built this way need some tweaking of library search paths afterwards, but that is all non-ROS specific (all of this is, actually).

If done correctly, this should avoid inadvertent mixing of libraries and headers of the two Boost versions.

Note that you'll probably have to clean out the `1.64` install you have in `/usr/local` already, and rebuild it with a suitable `PREFIX`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-25**:
It's not absolutely necessary to get the non-default Boost off the default search paths, but it's probably the easiest way to avoid running into any issues later. `/usr/local` is (I believe) searched first, so every `find_package(Boost ..)` is going to find it, and again: mixing is not a good idea.

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2017-10-25**:
I'll see if I can make the node link against (maybe even statically) some "locally" installed boost 1.64 while removing the latter from /usr/local and keeping only 1.58 in the system search paths. Prbbly gonna be a hell of a ride. I also hope to get rid of some weird node shutdown behavior by this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-25**:
It shouldn't be too difficult: dealing with multiple versions of libraries is something that CMake can do since a long time.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-25**:
Keep in mind though that 'the rest' of ROS Kinetic (ie: all libraries that you use) will still bring in Boost `1.58` artefacts. That is not going to change, and can still lead to issues.

The only way to really avoid that is to build ROS (all of it) from sources against `1.64`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-25**:
And finally: this problem - linking against different versions of dependencies in a single compilation unit - is not ROS specific. It's a universal problem when dealing with languages that support (dynamic) linking (ie: even Python has it).

It's called the *dependency hell*.

**Comment by [DangTran](https://answers.ros.org/users/53085/dangtran/) on 2020-05-22**:
For anyone having problems with multiple version dependency when working in ROS, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316523/how-to-include-two-different-versions-of-the-same-dependency-in-a-cmake-project) may useful. The example demonstrates very much @gvdhoom 's explanation